# Show div once clicked and hide when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I'm trying to show the #subscribe-pop div once a link is clicked and hide it when clicking anywhere outside it. I can get it to show and hide if I change the:

```
$('document').click(function() {
```

TO

```
$('#SomeOtherRandomDiv').click(function() {
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footleft">
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('subscribe-pop');">Click here to show div</a>
    <div id="subscribe-pop"><p>my content</p></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById("subscribe-pop");
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    $('document').click(function() {
        $('#subscribe-pop').hide(); //Hide the menus if visible
    });

    $('#subscribe-pop').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: Use `$(document)`, not `$('document')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to stop the event propagation in your container ('footleft' in this case), so the parent element don't notice the event was triggered.

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
 <div id="footleft">
    <a href="#" id='link'>Click here to show div</a>
    <div id="subscribe-pop"><p>my content</p></div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('html').click(function() {
    $('#subscribe-pop').hide();
 })

 $('#footleft').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });

 $('#link').click(function(e) {
     $('#subscribe-pop').toggle();
 });
```

See it working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yBGt/).

Comment: Awesome, this works great, thank you (and everyone else) for your replies :)

Comment: Understood, but still working on my side, even with the form. [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/4yBGt/2/). Also, make sure your html is in order. If this works, don't forget to check this answer as the solution. :)

Comment: Lovely solution, i was looking for this

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that the asker is trying to accomplish a jquery modal type of display of a div.

Should you like to check this [link](http://www.jacklmoore.com/demo/modal/modal2.html) out, the page upon load displays a modal div that drives your eye into the center of the screen because it dims the background.

Moreover, I compiled a short [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinIsNowOnline/P45bE/8/) for you to check on. if you are allowed to use jquery with your requirements, you can also check out their site.

Here is the code for showing or hiding your pop-up div

```
var toggleVisibility = function (){
     if($('#subscribe-pop').is(":not(:visible)") ){
            $('#subscribe-pop').show(); 
        }else{
             $('#subscribe-pop').hide(); 
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing `$(document).click()` to `$('html').click()` should solve the main problem.

Secondly, you do not need the `toggle_visibility()` function at all, you can simply do:

```
$('#subscribe-pop').toggle();
```

Ref: changed `body` to `html` as per this answer: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)